# How to call "public String name(Context context)" in java class

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, android-context

I'm writing native android code plugin for Worklight, it's look like:

```
public class Getimeiplugin extends CordovaPlugin {  
    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) 
            throws JSONException {
        if (action.equals("getimeiand")){
            try {
            String Strgetimei = getemei();  ///How to call public String get imei here
                final String responseText = Strgetimei + args.getString(0);
                cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {             
                        callbackContext.success(responseText); // Thread-safe.
                    }
                });
            } catch (JSONException e){
                callbackContext.error("Failed to parse parameters");
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String getemei(Context context)
    {
        TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr;
        mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String imei = mTelephonyMgr.getDeviceId();
         return imei;
        }
}
```

I don't known how to call `public String getimei(Context context)`, please anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing this line:

```
String Strgetimei = getemei();
```

to this:

```
String strGetimei = getemei(this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext());
```

or this:

```
String strGetimei = getemei(callBackContext);
```

I think one of those 2 will work.

you will then have to change this line:

```
final String responseText = Strgetimei + args.getString(0);
```

to this:

```
final String responseText = strGetimei + args.getString(0);
```

Definitely spend some time reading up on variable naming conventions.  You shouldn't be naming variables starting with capitalized letters.  That is reserved for Classes.

Comment: its say the method getApplicationContext() is underfined for type Getimeiplugin

Comment: check the edit.  I just looked up on stack overflow how to get to app context from a cordova plugin class.  Added a second edit too...

Comment: let me know if one of those 2 work... if not, we'll keep digging

Comment: also, are other classes going to be calling the getemei method?  if not, you should probably change it to a private method

Comment: it's work well now, thank you so much, you are so enthusiasm, look like i should learn more basic java syntax :(